# "unable to find valid certification path to requested target" even when vm option is specified

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, jvm

I'm running a spring boot app, but the bootRun fails due to `sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target` I have a .jks file in my project and set the path for the file as my truststore path in the bootRun task of my build.gradle. So I'm not sure why the program cannot find the certification path.

Here is by bootRun task in my build.gradle

```
...
bootRun {
 jvmArgs = [
             "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=$truststorePath - 
 Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit"

     ]
}
...
```

I'm using intelij for my IDEA

UPDATE

If I go up on my error stack, I was getting

```
I/O error on GET request for "https://some-end-point": PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException
```

Does that mean the program is finding my .jks file but the .jks file does not have the right certificate?